# magento paypal 'PayPal response hasn't required fields.'

Tags: magento, paypal

Tried to follow magento's own paypal integration for payment pro. and everything seemed to work fine untill I tried to process an order . The I get an error (in the log file) saying:

"PayPal response hasn't required fields."

and since I followed the magento paypal integration thingy to the letter. I hope someone else have bumped into this problem before and could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Well solved it myself.. found out that this error is magentos way of saying: paypal says, that the api information is wrong. So if you bump into this one go check your api credentials. :)

Comment: In my case credentials are right. Only some customers faces the problem.